# Printing to paper in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, printing

I am new to qt. I want to make a simple project that will print text from the printer. 
whenever I am using

```
   QPrinter printer;

 QPrintDialog *dialog = new QPrintDialog(&printer, this);
 dialog->setWindowTitle(tr("Print Document"));
 if (editor->textCursor().hasSelection())
     dialog->addEnabledOption(QAbstractPrintDialog::PrintSelection);
 if (dialog->exec() != QDialog::Accepted)
     return;
```

or this

```
 QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
 printer.setOutputFileName("print.ps");
 QPainter painter;
 painter.begin(&printer);

 for (int page = 0; page < numberOfPages; ++page) {

     // Use the painter to draw on the page.

     if (page != lastPage)
         printer.newPage();
 }

 painter.end();
```

I just copy pasted this to my mainwindow.cpp(and tried pasting it to main.cpp too),to check if it works. It does not. 
I am getting several errors like these

> mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual _*thiscall QPrinter::~QPrinter(void)" (*_imp_??1QPrinter@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(void)" (?on_pushButton_clicked@MainWindow@@AAEXXZ).

could someone tell me step by step, how  to print to a printer?
I also checked a lot online, but did not get any relevant tutorial , or even an example. 
so, PLEASE write it here instead of linking me to another page.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't configure your project (Visual C++, I assume?) properly. You need to add the Qt libraries in your project settings so that the linker will find them.

Comment: You probably missed the #include <QPrinter> statement?

Comment: whenever I am trying to include that, it is suggesting <QtPrintSupport/QPrinter>
I am using qtCreator and msvc2010
here is a snapshot:
http://i39.tinypic.com/2h82r74.jpg

Comment: @Sebastian No. Missing #includes usually lead to compiler errors, not linker errors.

Comment: your pro file does include ``CONFIG += gui``? Eventually you got different versions of Qt installed. Try copying QtGuiN.dll and QtGuiNd.dll to your executing path and check if it works. Use the dll's from your configured Qt-SDK-Path/bin

Comment: you were right. 
it was some version error. 
I have two versions. I used the other version. Works fine. 
now tell me how to print a text .

Comment: You print using the functions of the `QPainter`. They're all explained in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some quick research being kind of surprised by your comments. The QtPrintSupport did change, so use for Qt5 ([Detailed Description](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtprintsupport-module.html#details)):

In Pro file:
`QT += core gui printsupport`

In cpp file:
`#include <QtPrintSupport>`

For printing from your QTextEdit *editor use:

```
editor->document()->print(&printer);
```